# PHP uppercase to lowercase rewrite optimization?

Tags: php, redirect, uppercase, lowercase

I am using this PHP code to redirect any form of UPPERCASE in URI's to lowercase. There are three exceptions: if the URI includes either "adminpanel" or "search" there is no redirect, also if it already is lowercase there is no redirect

Do you see any way to improve the function in PHP?

```
$trailed = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pos1 = strpos($trailed,"adminpanel");
$pos2 = strpos($trailed,"search");
if ($pos1 === false && $pos2 === false && strlen($trailed) !== strlen(preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '',     $trailed))) {
    $trailed = strtolower($trailed);
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
    header('Location: http://'. $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $trailed);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: If you're running on Apache I would do this with Mod_Rewrite, not PHP: http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/ (You'd need to adjust the RewriteCond pattern to exclude "adminpanel" and "search".)

Comment: I'd love to, but going into the httpd.conf is not an option right now :(

Comment: 500 error with this code:

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
    RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]

Comment: I'm not a Mod_Rewrite guru, else I'd have posted an answer, not a comment. Nevertheless, the comments at that link indicate that RewriteMap works only in httpd.conf, not .htaccess. There are many articles about this subject online, though, so perhaps if you Google around you'll be able to find another solution.

Comment: Thank you Jordan, :) I spent about 20 minutes googling and only found the above mentioned solution or similar a couple of times. As I do not have access to the httpd.conf I saved the code in my snippets library for future use, but that is all I can do right now :(.

Comment: RewriteMap works just in httpd.conf and not in .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$trailed = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (!strpos($trailed,"admin") && !strpos($trailed,"search") && preg_match('/[[:upper:]]/', $trailed)) {
  $trailed = strtolower($trailed);
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently'); 
  header('Location: http://'. $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $trailed);
  exit;
}
```

Taking a combined approach this code is about 140% faster than the first one. Only one if statement with the strpos inside and a preg_match instead of string length comparison.

Sorry I don't have the reputation yet to vote up the answers that lead to the final version and thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this will fail to redirect in the case that a URI has mixed case. Is this intended? Also, might using string comparison of $trailed and strtolower($trailed) be less verbose than using a regular expression in the third clause of the if statement on line 4?

Comment: It will redirect with all kinds of mixed cases. As far as the regexp is concerned it is a lot faster than the string comparison :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of comparing the original string and the result of preg_replace() you could let preg_match() test, if there is an upper case letter in the string.

```
if ( preg_match('/[[:upper:]]/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) {
  if ( false===stripos($trailed, 'adminpanel') && false===stripos($trailed, 'search') {
    // strotolower
    // ...
  }
}
```

(This might not be relevant now but as a side note: pcre has some unicode support. Instead of [:upper:] you'd use \p{Lu} to test for unicode upper case letters, see http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)